# Angular 5 View not updating with Model

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I am using Angular version 5.

I am loading data from Google Places Web Service using Angular-Maps. I run a service to fetch the data and load it in a variable say 'data'. In my component I subscribe to 'data', so whenever the value of 'data' changes, my view should update.

But surprisingly, when the value of 'data' changes and I am able to record the change with console.log the View does not update ? It only updates when I interact with some other element in the view.

This is a snapshot of my service

```
  private rs = new BehaviorSubject<Object>(undefined);
  rd = this.rs.asObservable();

  constructor(private mapi: MapsAPILoader)
  {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() =>
    {
      this.ps = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
    });
  }

  fPi(pid: string)
  {
    this.ps.getDetails(
    { placeId: pid }, (pr, status) =>
    {
      if(status === 'OK')
      {
        this.extract(pr);
      }
    });
  }

  extract(pr)
  {
    let details = [];
    if (pr.formatted_address)
    {
      details.push({"field": "Address", "value": placeResult.formatted_address});
    }

    if (pr.international_phone_number)
    {
      details.push({"field": "Phone Number", "value": placeResult.international_phone_number});
    }
    this.update(placeDetails);
  }

  update(rd: Object)
  {
    console.log(rd);
    this.rs.next(rd);
  }
```

This is my component part where is susbcribe

```
this.service.rd.subscribe(rd =>
    {
      if (rd)
        this.data = Object.values(rd);
    });
```

And in HTML I simply do

```
<div *ngIf="data">
    {{data}}
</div>
```

So, what is wrong here and what can be done to get it right ?

Comment: It would be good to provide some code so that we can see what is it that you are doing wrong.

Comment: hope you have performed binding properly ...

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic code added please help

Comment: Inject ChangeDetectorRef in component and call this.cdr.detectChanges() in subdcribe callback after assigning new data

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk is it a good practice to use ChangeDetector even when we have a data binding ?

Comment: Are you using OnPush change detection?

Comment: As @TomaszKula has suggested, try using OnPush change detection strategy. You are trying to monitor the changes of the reference type which might not report the changes. Also, try calling `this.data = rd` without going through `Object.value(rd)` just to see whether it works.

Comment: If some lib uses async calls - they may be not monkey-patched by ng zone so may not cause automatic change detection. In that case you should invoke it yourself

Comment: @SK I don't think it's a good practice. Usually there is a way to avoid using ChangeDetection ref directly. It's the last thing I'd reach for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I handle this same type of situation in one of my components. The main thing here is that I create an Observable and then assign the response of the behavior subject to the Observable. I then use the async pipe in the template which will make sure every thing gets unsubscribed properly. Here is an example of almost the same hing you are doing above:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { PitchingInitiativesService } from '../../services/pitching-initiatives.service';
import { EventService } from 'app/services/events/events.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-pitching-table',
    templateUrl: './pitching-table.component.html'
})

export class PitchingTableComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() searchText = '';
    searchKey = 'name';
    table: any = [];

    constructor(
        private pitching: PitchingInitiativesService,
        private events: EventService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pitching.getPitchingSubject();
        this.pitching.pitchingResponse$.subscribe(response => this.table = response);
    }

    editPi(id = null) {
        this.events.pitchingId(id);
    }

    editMilestones(id) {
        this.events.milestonesId(id);
    }

    archivePi(id) {
        this.pitching.postArchivePitch(id).subscribe(response => {
            this.pitching.getPitchingSubject();
        });
    }

}
```

and then in my template I iterate the Observable using the async pipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of table | async | filter: searchText : searchKey">
```

I hope this helps...